# Comparar elementos de dos dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo 2 Dataframes, `Articulos`, e `Inventario`. En el df Inventario tengo los id_articulo y 90 dias de su demanda y stock. mi idea es en el df inventario me quede asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces mi idea es comparar el idarticulo del df inventario y que compare el valor de la fila anterior.
Quisiera hacer algo como esto:

```
for i in range(articulos['idarticulo']):
       for j in range(inventario):
            if( i == j['id_articulo']):
               #comparar si el id de articulo es igual, insertar en la columna stock inicio, lo que hay en stockfinal
```

Mi problema es que tengo que comparar con el valor de la fila anterior y esto me esta consumiendo.

Se agradece info ya que soy nuevo en python.

Saludos,
Lucas

Comment: Hola @lucas-damian, podrias pegar en texto una parte de los dataframes, para que sea mas claro y para intentar replicarlo. Saludos.

Comment: el de articulos solo tiene id_articulo 1 2 3 4 5. y el de inventario, tengo que hacer el update ya que solo tengo cargados los dias 0. y la idea es que se vayan cargando como muestra en pantalla

Comment: He leido varias veces la pregunta, y también el comentario y sigo sin entenderlo. ¿Puedes poner código que muestre concretamente qué hay en el dataframe `articulos`? Si sólo contiene los ids de los artículos como dices ¿para qué lo necesitas? ¿No estan ya esos ids en el dataframe `inventario`? ¿Qué contiene este otro dataframe? ¿Tiene las filas ordenadas por `id_articulo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acabo de hacerlo, nose si funciona bien pero lo hice de tal manera, seguro hay una mejor optimización:

```
newTestNP = inventario.head(n=400).values // aca lo pase a un array
py= newTestNP.copy() // aca lo copie
# 0 id_articulo 1 id_fecha 3demanda 4devolucion 5stock_inicio 8m_stock_final

    for i in range(len(newTestNP)):
        for j in range(len(newTestNP[i])):
            if(py[i][0] == py[j][0] and py[j][1] >= 0 ): 
                py[i][8] = py[i][5] - py[i][3] + py[i][4] 
                if(py[i][0] == py[i+1][0] and i<=len(newTestNP)): 
                    py[i+1][5] = py[i][8]
```